# Asp.net: I want make two tasks at same time (uploading and navigating for example)

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, upload

I'm searching a way to do two tasks at same time in asp.net, exactly made a box for uploading that stays on the site web and have the possibility to navigate at same time.
I already looked for MultiThreading but I've yet done anything with it!!

Answer (score 1):

As @atp9 has said, use Task.Run(). Here is a code snippet to help you out on how to use it. So from what you said, let's say we have these two methods that you want to run on separate tasks:

```
public void Upload(string dataToUpload)
{
  .... // your Upload code
}

public void Navigate(string navTo)
{
  .... // your Navigate code
}
```

then somewhere on your ASP.NET code base, you'll need to Execute the two tasks (and make sure those methods are accessible as well). Here I have them inside class called **MyClass** so I can just instantiate an instance and call the methods:

```
var mc = new MyClass();
var uploadTask = Task.Run(() => { mc.Upload("hello world"); });
var navigateTask = Task.Run(() => { mc.Navigate("to the world"); });
```

Of course, this is just an oversimplified example but this should give you an idea of how it works. For more details about running multiple Tasks, see this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674889.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Bairose and apt9!
Is the task can still runing even if I go from a page to an other page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Task.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) method that actually runs on a Threadpool. That helps you to deal with FileUpload and navigating in you app.